# rails 3 not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select all records that are not null from my table using where method

```
MyModel.where(:some_id => !nil)
```

but it doesn't work, is there any other solution to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a string rather than a hash

```
MyModel.where("some_id is not null")
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it using the [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) syntax (which has the bonus of being database independent):

```
MyModel.where(MyModel.arel_table['some_id'].not_eq(nil))
```

Comment: Nice... I feel arel is yet a bit underrated among rails developers

Comment: @lucapette agreed, though the quasi-inexistent documentation may be to blame for that...

Comment: @BenoitGarret Thank you, you saved the day! I had a filter query working under sqlite3, but broken on Postgres. I didn't know Arel. Thank you for the hint. I will look into it.

Comment: Bonus points for ugly non-obvious code. Rails needs to make this better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
MyModel.where("some_id IS NOT NULL")
```